# How can I lock the mouse position in WinUI 3 Apps

Tags: winapi, mouse, winui-3

I have a `SwapChainPanel` which renders 3d content. Now I want to use the mouse to rotate objects. Therefore I need a way to lock the mouse position but read out mouse movements, when the mouse is inside the panel area and a button is clicked.

Alternative if I could place the mouse at the last clicked position would also work.

The mouse has to keeps its default behaviour on "uncklick" state, since there are other UI Elements inside the window (but not the inside the panel).

I played around with `CapturePointer`, but with no success.

Any ideas is welcome.

---

As requested, here my `CapturePointer` code:

```cs
public MainWindow() {
    ...
    View3dControl.PointerPressed += View3dControl_PointerPressed;
    View3dControl.PointerMoved += View3dControl_PointerMoved;
    View3dControl.PointerReleased += View3dControl_PointerReleased;
}

private void View3dControl_PointerPressed(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool hasCapture = ((SwapChainPanel)sender).CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
    Debug.WriteLine("hasCapture = {0}", hasCapture); // <-- is fired, shows true
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void View3dControl_PointerMoved(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("PointerMoved");  // <-- is fired
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void View3dControl_PointerReleased(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("PointerReleased"); // <-- is fired
    ((SwapChainPanel)sender).ReleasePointerCapture(e.Pointer);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

All events are fired, but the mouse pointer still moves on mouse movement.

I want to stop moving the mouse pointer, so that the mouse movement is not limited by the screen borders. Hiding the cursor while the mouse is pressed would be nice too.

Comment: Why not use dragging to rotate and scrolling to scale as the public do?

Comment: Since dragging will be stopped, if the mouse reaches the desktop borders.

Comment: *"I played around with `CapturePointer`, but with no success."* - That appears to be the proper solution. Please show what you've tried and how it failed to exhibit the desired behavior.